# Saving checked status from a checkbox into the database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on a online test application in asp.net and i'm finding trouble in saving the checked answer status back to database, i.e once i click on next button in my aspx page these 2 things should happen

1)It should capture the currently checked option and add the value for that particular option as true into my database IS_Marked column.

2)It also should pull out the next set of question and Options

The latter is fine but i'm not getting any clue about how to save the checkd answer back into database

My aspx has 4 check boxes

and my next button click event is as follows,

protected void BtnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

if (qid == maxid)//checks whether current que id is equal to last que id in DB

```
{
     BtnNext.Enabled = false; //if its last que then next button is disabled
}
else
{      
     BtnPrevious.Enabled = true; // if not last question next button is enabled

     QuestionSet q = new QuestionSet();  //Question set is an entity to hold que text and options list
     StudentB b = new StudentB(); //object of my business class
     q = b.GetQuestion(1, 1, qid, 'N', 0);//passing student id, test id, question id, action taken, i.e button clicked(prev, next, last, first) and selected question(i.e any question that is present)
     qid = Convert.ToInt32(q.Question_Id);

     LblQStn.Text = q.Question_Text;
     CheckBox1.Text = q.Options[0].Option_Text;//talking to business and model layer and getting que and ans from database and giving to checkboxes
     CheckBox2.Text = q.Options[1].Option_Text;
     CheckBox3.Text = q.Options[2].Option_Text;
     CheckBox4.Text = q.Options[3].Option_Text;
    }
}
```

now when he checks any answer i need to save its status as marked into the database
Any solution is highly appreciated,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well first you need to set up the connection to database. example:
//sqlString is your connectionstring//

```
    dbconn = New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("sqlString"))
    dbconn.Open()
    strsql = "INSERT INTO IS_Marked ([Mark]) VALUES ('" + Bedrijf + "')"
    dbcomm = New SqlCommand(strsql, dbconn)
    dbcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    dbconn.Close()
```

This will be your basic sql command.

As you can see I ues ([yourvalue]) that what we are going to do next.

```
    Dim dbconn As SqlConnection
    Dim dbcomm As SqlCommand
    Dim strsql, Checked_Mark As String

    Mark = YourCheckBox.CheckedValue
```

So your final result will be like this:

```
    Dim dbconn As SqlConnection
    Dim dbcomm As SqlCommand
    Dim strsql, Mark As String

    Mark = YourCheckBox.CheckedValue
    dbconn = New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("sqlString"))
    dbconn.Open()
    strsql = "INSERT INTO IS_Marked ([Mark]) VALUES ('" + Bedrijf + "')"
    dbcomm = New SqlCommand(strsql, dbconn)
    dbcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    dbconn.Close()
```